# how to initialize multiple objects at once in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to initialize multiple objects like this.

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
```

Is there a way to initialize them as

```
DataTable dt1, dt2, dt3, dt4 = new DataTable();
```

If I use above, there are no compile errors but there are runtime errors says `An Object reference not set to an instance.`

How can I achieve this.

Comment: A List<DataTable> with init syntax?

Comment: Too many datatables. Initialize variables just before you use them. Limit their scope to minimal. If you do operations on 4 DataTables then there is a big chance you are duplicating code or keeping them in higher scope that they need to be in.

Comment: No, there´s no such way, you have to initialize them one by one. But you can do so in a single line: `Datatable t1 = new DataTable(), t2 = new DataTable(), t3 = new DataTable(), ...;`

Comment: Never put few operators in one line. The code becomes difficult to read.

Comment: With no context at all I have to ask, why?

Comment: Why don't you use a DataTable  Enumerable? You can at least do something like this 
 DataTable dt1 = new DataTable(), dt2 = new DataTable(), dt3 = new DataTable(), dt4 = new DataTable(); to be sure to have a new object istance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there´s no such way, you have to initialize them one by one.

Your error appears because `dt1` to `dt3` are initialized to `null`, only `dt4` has a value. Thus doing anything with `d1` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

But you can do so in a single line:

```
DataTable t1 = new DataTable(), t2 = new DataTable(), t3 = new DataTable(), t4 = new DataTable();
```

Even better would be a list/array:

```
var tables = new[] { new DataTable(), new DataTdable(), new DataTable(), new DataTable() };
```

or even

```
var tables = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(x => new DataTable());
```

Comment: In the last example you should invoke .ToArray()